# how to call the superclass in ext js 3.4 within a variable

Tags: extjs, extjs3

Does anyone know how you can successfully call the superclass in ext js 3.4?
In my example code I can't seem to get the superclass working on a panel.

```
MyWindow = Ext.extend(MyWindowUi, {
    initComponent: function() {
        MyWindow.superclass.initComponent.call(this);
        this.createTextField();
    },  
    createTextField : function() {  
        var p = new Ext.Panel({
            title: 'somepanel',
            initComponent: function() {
                console.log('init component');
                console.log(this);
                this.superclass.initComponent.call(this); //NOT WORKING??
            }
        });
        this.add(p);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `Ext.Panel.superclass.initComponent.call(this)` instead.

Comment: I tried using the superclass, but that did not rendered the panel.
The Ext.Panel.prototype.initComponent.call(this); worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

It is not working because you are not calling the initComponent of Ext.Panel when creating p.  If you are going to override a method with a superclass call of the previous method an Ext.extend would be cleaner if no scope tricks are needed.

You could also do something like :

```
   createTextField : function() {  
    var p = new Ext.Panel({
        title: 'somepanel'
    }),
    oldInit = p.initComponent;

    p.initComponent = function() {
        console.log('init component');
        console.log(this);
        oldInit.call(this);
    }

    this.add(p);
}
```

Or something like:

```
createTextField : function() {  
    var p = new Ext.Panel({
        title: 'somepanel',
        initComponent: function() {
            console.log('init component');
            console.log(this);
            Ext.Panel.prototype.initComponent.call(this);
        }
    });
    this.add(p);
}
```

But they are both ugly imo.

Comment: Thanks! super, the option: Ext.Panel.prototype.initComponent.call(this);  works great!